# How to find if one part of an array is the same as a integer?

Tags: java, arrays

I am making a small project.  I have a integer `inum`, and a array of strings `fill`.  I am trying to see which part of the array `fill` is equal to `inum`.  Here is my code below:

```
        String input = scan.nextLine();
        int inum = Integer.parseInt(input);
            for(int k = 0; k < 9; k++){
                String cool = "hello";
                cool = "" + inum;
                if(fill[k] == cool){
                    fill[k] = "0";
```

It seems that the computer is not changing `fill[k]` to 0.  Does anyone know why this is so?  Help is appreciated!

Comment: Do you know where the other one is?

Comment: You have the link above your question.